# Error while executing pl sql stored procedure with sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

When I'm trying to execure following query:

```
 declare
 v_rc    sys_refcursor;
wfrt_a1 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a2 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a3 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a4 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a5 varchar2(800 byte);

             wfrt_a6 varchar2(800 byte);
              wfrt_a7 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a8 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a9 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a10 varchar2(800 byte);

             wfrt_a11 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a12 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a13 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a14 varchar2(800 byte);

             wfrt_a15 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a16 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a17 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a18 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a19 varchar2(800 byte);

             wfrt_a20 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a21 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a22 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a23 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a24 varchar2(800 byte);

             wfrt_a25 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a26 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a27 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a28 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a29 varchar2(800 byte);

             wfrt_a30 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a31 varchar2(800 byte);
              wfrt_a32 varchar2(800 byte);
               wfrt_a33 varchar2(800 byte);
                wfrt_a34 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a35 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a36 varchar2(800 byte);

                              wfrt_a37 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a38 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a39 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a40 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a41 varchar2(800 byte);
             wfrt_a42 varchar2(800 byte);
               begin
 execute My_Procedure_Name (:v_rc  ,'Investments Series','31-12-2012','Dealer  Group','All Adv');  -- This returns an open cursor
loop
 fetch v_rc into wfrt_a1, wfrt_a2, wfrt_a3, wfrt_a4,wfrt_a5,wfrt_a6,wfrt_a7,wfrt_a8,wfrt_a9,wfrt_a10,wfrt_a11,wfrt_a12,wfrt_a13,wfrt_a14,wfrt_a15,wfrt_a16,wfrt_a17
 ,wfrt_a18,wfrt_a19,wfrt_a20,wfrt_a21,wfrt_a22,wfrt_a23,wfrt_a24,wfrt_a25,wfrt_a26,wfrt_a27,wfrt_a28,wfrt_a29,wfrt_a30,wfrt_a31,wfrt_a32,wfrt_a33,wfrt_a34,wfrt_a35
 ,wfrt_a36,wfrt_a37,wfrt_a38,wfrt_a39,wfrt_a40,wfrt_a41,wfrt_a42;
 exit when v_rc%NOTFOUND;  -- Exit the loop when we've run out of data
 dbms_output.put_line('Row: '||v_rc%ROWCOUNT||' # '||wfrt_a1||','||wfrt_a2||','||wfrt_a3||','||wfrt_a4||','||wfrt_a5||','||wfrt_a6||','||wfrt_a7||','||wfrt_a8||','||wfrt_a9 
 ||','||wfrt_a10||','||wfrt_a11||','||wfrt_a12||','||wfrt_a13||','||wfrt_a14||','||wfrt_a15||','||wfrt_a16||','||wfrt_a17
 ||','||wfrt_a18||','||wfrt_a19||','||wfrt_a20||','||wfrt_a21||','||wfrt_a22||','||wfrt_a23||','||wfrt_a24||','||wfrt_a25
 ||','||wfrt_a26||','||wfrt_a27||','||wfrt_a28||','||wfrt_a29||','||wfrt_a30||','||wfrt_a31||','||wfrt_a32||','||wfrt_a33
 ||','||wfrt_a34||','||wfrt_a35||','||wfrt_a36||','||wfrt_a37||','||wfrt_a38||','||wfrt_a39||','||wfrt_a40||','||wfrt_a41||','||wfrt_a42);
end loop;
  close v_rc;
 end;
```

I'm getting below error:
 ORA-06550: line 56,column 9:
    PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol
    "My_Procedure_Name" when expecting one of the following
    :=.(@%;immediate

Note: My procedure is like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USER.My_Procedure_Name (c1                IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                           code IN     VARCHAR2,
                                           date  IN     VARCHAR2,
                                           group     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                          adv        IN     VARCHAR2
                                          )
```

PLease suggest, where I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly `execute` a procedure call from within PL/SQL, so remove that word:

```
begin
    My_Procedure_Name (v_rc  , 'Investments Series','31-12-2012',
        'All Dealer Group','All Adviser');  -- This returns an open cursor
    loop
```

Within PL/SQL you do have `execute immediate` for dynamic SQL; the error message is because it's seeing your procedure name when it expectes to see the word `immediate`. You may be confusing it with the SQL*Plus and SQL Developer `execute` command, which is shorthand for a small anonymous block.

You were passing `:v_rc` as the first argument, which indicates a bind variable, when you really just want the locally declared `v_rc`. If it didn't comlain about that then you may already have that defined as a client variable, of a different type if you got a 'wrong number or types' error from that.

Passing a string instead of a date seems a little odd too.

Comment: thanks for input. But I'm getting this error : Now, its saying, "wrong number of types of arguments in call to 'My_Stored_Procedure' line 56,colimn 2. PL/SQL:statement ignored"

Comment: @bapi - probably because of the colon before the first argument; have you done `variable v_rc number` or something in your client before running this block?

Comment: The date conversion is taken care insite SP, I don't think, there is any problem with date parameter.Also, this is the way I'm passing the date from SSRS report frontend. However, when I execute query with your suggested modification,getting another error: "Return type of result set variables or query do not match" - I did little modification to my question.  How to reslove this? Thanks.

Comment: @bapi - return type of what? I'm confused... what's the full error stack for that? In the procedure, when you open the cursor, do you have a different number of select list items, or different types, to the 42 variables you're fetching into?

Comment: THis is what I'm getting when I clicked details: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match 

Cause: Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match declared return type of a result set variable, or declared types of two Result Set variables do not match.

Action: Change the program statement or declaration. Verify what query the variable actually refers to during execution.

Comment: @bapi - exactly, check the select in your procedure. You haven't shown that. You might have a different number of columns selected; or they might be different types to the wfrt_a1 etc. local variables. I can't guess what your procedure is actually doing.